# Why is my panel is not refreshing?

Tags: asp.net

This is the first time i writing something in ASP.NET :)

I have wrote some Control that contain button and panel. 
When pressing the button - some Action ( delegate ) is call ==> this 
Action call some web service ( asynchronous call using Task ) and 
when i get the response from the web service i call the 
callback method that according to the web service answer 
i change the back color of the panel.

But even when i stop on the breakpoint of the callback ( the color change of the control ) - i don't see that the panel back color is changes.

I try to change it from the browser - and i succeed to change it
I also able to change the color from the ASP design page.

I don't have any clue why the panel color is not change. 
How can i solve it ?

The control code==>

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="TrafficLights.ascx.cs" Inherits="Control1" %>
```

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="131px" Height="40px" 
    CssClass="Site.css" style="margin: 10px" Font-Underline="True" />

<asp:Panel Height="10" runat="server" />


<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="180px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>


<asp:Button ID=ActionButton CssClass="Site.css"  runat="server" 
    BackColor="Azure" Width="120px" Heigh="40px" Text="Action" style="margin-left: 30px; height: 26px;" onclick="ActionButton_Click"  />
```

```
public enum Color_
    {
        Red,
        Yellow,
        Green
    };

    public Color_ Color_A
    {
        set
        {
            switch( value )
            {
                case Color_.Red:
                    {
                        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    break;
                case Color_.Yellow:
                    {
                        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    break;
                case Color_.Green:
                    {
                        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    protected void ActionButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( actionOnButtonClickEvent != null )
        {
            actionOnButtonClickEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you set backcolor from codebehind like `panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;` or using some different technique..

Comment: Are you using ajax to update the panel? It would be good if you can share some code.

Comment: I really new in this asp ... don't use ajax - do i need to use ajax ? how to use it anyway ?

Comment: Can you put here the markup (especially the button) and maybe the button handler routine as well ?